# How to set color of 7 textviews in recyclerview adapter?Set color according to days array recieved from back&

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Here below, I am posting my json in which I am getting a array for days.
If array contains [5,6,7] change the color of 3 textviews ie. Th,Fr,Sa in card view.

```
[

{
    "id":112,
    "patient":"sandeepsingh@innotical.com",
    "salt":"sdfdsf",
    "doctor":"Dr",
    "amount":null,
    "unit":null,
    "method":null,
    "date":"2006-04-02",
    "note":null,
    "frequency":null,
    "reminder":[
    ]
},
{
    "id":114,
    "patient":"sandeepsingh@innotical.com",
    "salt":"Zaleplon",
    "doctor":"ufuffu",
    "amount":"13",
    "unit":1,
    "method":1,
    "date":"2016-06-02",
    "note":"chchjf",
    "frequency":null,
    "reminder":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "time":" ",
            "days":[
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                6,
                7
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "time":" ",
            "days":[
                5,
                6,
                7
            ]
        }
    ]
}

]
```

and also here i am posting my cardview image in which I want to change color position wise.I want a complete solution thanx in advance.[image]

My Parsing Code Below.

```
 @Override
                public void success(List<SavedMedicationPojo> savedMedicationPojo, Response response) {




                    savedMedicationPojo1.addAll(savedMedicationPojo);
                   // medSetter.setMedicationPojo(savedMedicationPojo1);

                  if (savedMedicationPojo.size()>0){

                    for (int i = 0; i < savedMedicationPojo.size(); i++) {

                       // SavedMedicationPojo medication = new SavedMedicationPojo();


                        mSaltIdList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getId());
                        mSaltList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getSalt());
                        mSaltAmountList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getAmount());
                        mSaltUnitList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getUnit());
                        mSaltMethodList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getMethod());
                        mSaltDateList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getDate());
                        mSaltNoteList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getNote());
                        mSaltDoctorList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getDoctor());
                        mSaltFrequencyList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getFrequency());
                       // savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().get(i).
                       int msize = savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().size();
                        /*if(msize==0)
                        {ArrayList<Integer> mDaysList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            mReminderDaysHashMap.put(i, mDaysList);
                        }*/
                        for (int j = 0;j< savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().size();j++){
                            mReminderId.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().get(j).getId());
                            mReminderTime.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().get(j).getTime());
                                ArrayList<Integer> mDaysList= new ArrayList<Integer>();

                                for (int k = 0; k < savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().get(j).getDays().size(); k++) {
                                    mDaysList.add(savedMedicationPojo.get(i).getReminder().get(j).getDays().get(k));
                                }
                                mReminderDaysHashMap.put(j, mDaysList);
                           // }

                        }


                    }


                    mDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  }else{

                      mNoDataView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }

                }
```

my xml for cardview as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardChildGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="05dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/timeBellView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="02dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bellView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="02dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/alarmBell"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"

                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/bell" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bellView">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeDigit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="05dp"
                android:text="08:30"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeUnit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/timeDigit"
                android:layout_margin="05dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timeDigit"
                android:text="AM"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeUnitView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timeView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="05dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

           &lt;!&ndash; <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeUnit"
                android:text="AM"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />&ndash;&gt;



        </RelativeLayout>-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/switchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="05dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timeView">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/alarmPowerSwitch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/daysView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/timeBellView"
        android:layout_margin="02dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:onClick="Sunday"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="SU" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sunday"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="MO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tuesday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/monday"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="TU" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wednesday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tuesday"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="WE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thursday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wednesday"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="TH" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thursday"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="FR" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saturday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="01dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/friday"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="SA" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter class below.

public class AlarmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;


private List<String> myDataSet;
private static String KEY1;
// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
private boolean loading;
private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
private static String TAG = "DATA_ADAPTER";
private static ArrayList<String> mSavedTime = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> mTimeUnit = new ArrayList<>();
private static String mCurrentHour;
private static String mCurrentMinute;

private static Context context;

private static int mBellCount = 1;
private static int mSunCount = 1;
private static int mMonCount = 1;
private static int mTueCount = 1;
private static int mWedCount = 1;
private static int mThuCount = 1;
private static int mFriCount = 1;
private static int mSatCount = 1;

private static ArrayList<Integer> mDaysArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> mRecievedDays = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

/*public AlarmAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<String> mSavedTime,
                            String mUserSavedPin, ArrayList<Integer> mFileId, Integer mFamilyMemberId,
                            String mResponseToken, ArrayList<String> mFileDate, ArrayList<String> mFileUrl,
                            ArrayList<String> mFileDescription) {*/

public AlarmAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<String> mTime,ArrayList<String> mTimeUnit,String mCurrentHour,String mCurrentMinute) {


    this.mSavedTime = mTime;
    this.mTimeUnit = mTimeUnit;
    this.mCurrentHour = mCurrentHour;
    this.mCurrentMinute = mCurrentMinute;
    /*this.mSavedTime = mSavedTime;
    this.mFileId = mFileId;
    this.mUserSavedPin = mUserSavedPin;
    this.mFamilyMemberId = mFamilyMemberId;
    this.mResponseToken = mResponseToken;
    this.mFileDate = mFileDate;
    this.mFileUrl = mFileUrl;
    this.mFileDescription = mFileDescription;*/
    this.context = context;
    mSharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences("AlarmAdapterSharedPreferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();


        recyclerView
                .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                           int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        if (!loading
                                && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                            // End has been reached
                            // Do something
                            if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                            }
                            loading = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mSavedTime.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.saved_alarm_card, parent, false);

        vh = new StudentViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.more_progress_item, parent, false);

        vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
    }

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof StudentViewHolder) {





        ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mTimeDigitText.setText(mSavedTime.get(position));
        ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mTimeUnitText.setText(mTimeUnit.get(position));
        //  ((StudentViewHolder) holder).dateField.setText(mFileDate.get(position));

       if (ActivityUserMedication.mReminderDaysHashMap.get(position).contains(1)){
           ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mSundayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));

       }

            mRecievedDays.add(ActivityUserMedication.savedMedicationPojo1.get(1).getReminder().get(1).getDays().get(1));

       /* if (mRecievedDays.contains(1)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mSundayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else if (mRecievedDays.contains(2)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mMondayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else if (mRecievedDays.contains(3)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mTuesdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else if (mRecievedDays.contains(4)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mWednesdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else if (mRecievedDays.contains(5)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mThursdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else if (mRecievedDays.contains(6)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mFridayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else if (mRecievedDays.contains(7)){
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mSaturdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorProfilePrimary));
        }
        else{
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mSundayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mMondayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mTuesdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mWednesdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mThursdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mFridayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mSaturdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorSecondary));

        }*/



       /* if(position==1)
        {
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mSaturdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue_color));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mWednesdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue_color));
            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).mTuesdayButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue_color));

        }*/







        } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}

public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSavedTime.size();
}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}


//
public class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView mTimeDigitText;
    public TextView mTimeUnitText;
    private SwitchCompat mAlarmButtonPower;
    private ImageView mAlarmBellImage;

    private TextView mSundayButton;
    private TextView mMondayButton;
    private TextView mTuesdayButton;
    private TextView mWednesdayButton;
    private TextView mThursdayButton;
    private TextView mFridayButton;
    private TextView mSaturdayButton;

    public CardView cardView1;



    public StudentViewHolder(View v) {

        super(v);



        mTimeDigitText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeDigit);
        mTimeUnitText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeUnit);
        mAlarmBellImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.alarmBell);
        mAlarmButtonPower = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.alarmPowerSwitch);

        mSundayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sunday);
        mMondayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.monday);
        mTuesdayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
        mWednesdayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
        mThursdayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.thursday);
        mFridayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.friday);
        mSaturdayButton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.saturday);

      //  mAlarmBellImage.setId(getAdapterPosition()+100);
        mAlarmBellImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mAlarmBellImage.setId(getAdapterPosition()+100);
        //v.findViewById(R.id.alarmBell).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.sunday).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.monday).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.tuesday).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.wednesday).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.thursday).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.friday).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.saturday).setOnClickListener(this);

        Log.d(TAG, "StudentViewHolder: "+mDaysArrayList);
        mAlarmButtonPower.setChecked(true);
        if (mAlarmButtonPower.isChecked()) {
            mBellCount=2;

            mAlarmBellImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bell_touch));
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Activated!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            mAlarmBellImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bell));
            Toast.makeText(context, "First Activate Your Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mAlarmButtonPower.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                switch (buttonView.getId()) {

                    case R.id.alarmPowerSwitch:

                        if (!isChecked) {
                            mAlarmBellImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bell));
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is off!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {

                          //  AlarmReceiver.stopRingtone();
                           // alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
                            mAlarmBellImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bell_touch));
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is on!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });







    }





    }
}

public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In the adapter and corresponding view holder class you can do

Answer (score 0):

While setting custom adapter values for your cards you can parse your JSON array values and using if else conditional statements set the desired color of the TextViews.

To get the specific code you need to share your code of how and where you have parsed your JSON data and you adapter class for the card view.

Comment: give me ur Email id.

Comment: or You just tell me how can I add days array in a hashmap<integer,ArrayList<Integer>>

Comment: I am getting problem when reminder array is 0.Then I am unable to add it in hashmap that days array is zero

Comment: Check for null on your HashMap using size() function on your HashMap<K,V> object .

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of any textview by using this code:

```
txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
```

And if you want to add a check for week days following code will work:

1. First of all parse your days in list or array,
2. Search if your days list contains day number like this:

   if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("1")){
       ...
       }
3. Reset background color of all textview and Change color of specific day textview if your list contains that day like this:

   // Reset Color 
        txtViewSunday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txtViewMonday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txtViewTuesday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txtViewWednesday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txtViewThursday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txtViewFriday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        txtViewSaturday.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

   ```
   // Update color 
   if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("1")){
    txtViewSunday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }else if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("2")){
    txtViewMonday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }else if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("3")){
    txtViewTuesday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }else if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("4")){
    txtViewWednesday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }else if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("5")){
    txtViewThursday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }else if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("6")){
    txtViewFriday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }else if (Arrays.asList(days).contains("7")){
    txtViewSaturday.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
   }
   ```

you have to write this code in your adapter.

Comment: I am getting problem while parsing.When reminder array is 0 then I am not able to add it in my hashmap according to its position.

Comment: if it is 0 then only reset textview else set color accoding to the the days number

Comment: I had earlier added a check as u can see above I have commented those lines because I was unable to put zero item at its correct position in hashmap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113882/discussion-between-arora-and-anjali).